# $0<x<y<z<1, P(z-x<1/3)=$?

Tags: integration, order-statistics

I'm trying to solve a question about 'order statistics'.
$X, Y, Z$ follow uniform distributions between 0 to 1.
$(X , Y, Z \sim U(0,1))$

An unequality is given that $0< X < Y < Z < 1$. 
What is the probability of $(Z - X < 1/3)$?

I can easily calculate the density function of $X, Y, Z$ that $f(x, y, z) = 6.$

I think I should solve a triple integral problem. 
A cube is given that $0 < X , Y, Z < 1$.

And two conditions are given

$$0 < X < Y < Z < 1,$$

$$Z-X <1/3.$$

Is it a right way to solve this question?
I'm a bit of a dummy so a thorough explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did not state that $X,Y,Z$ are independent, nor otherwise specify their joint distribution. That information should be there.
$$\begin{align}
& \Pr(Z-X<1/3\mid X<Y<Z) = \frac{\Pr(X<Y<Z\ \&\ Z-X<1/3)}{\Pr(X<Y<Z)} \\
= {} & 6\Pr(X<Y<Z\ \&\ Z-X<1/3) = 6\Pr(X<Y <Z<\frac 1 3 + X).
\end{align}$$
If $(X,Y,Z)$ is uniformly distributed in the unit cube, finding this last expression amounts to finding the volume of the polyhedron defined by these inequalities. $\qquad$

Answer (score -1):

I think it is easier to find $P(z-x>1/3)$.
Then $1/3 < z < 1$, $0 < x < z-1/3$, and $x<y<z$.